# Laravel Sail : Changes to php.ini not taking effect

Tags: php, laravel-sail

What is the correct way of updating `php.ini` for Laravel Sail?

I've run `phpinfo()` and it shows `/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini` as "Loaded Configuration File" and `/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini` as one of the "additional `.ini` files parsed".

Any changes to `/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini` do not show in `phpinfo()`. Also tried copying this to `/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini` (with non-default values) but these do not show up either.

Also tried `/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini`.

Running on Windows 10 with WSL2.

Tried stopping Sail and also closing and reopening all the WSL2 (Ubuntu) windows and rerunning Sail.

What am I missing? Many thanks for a kind soul who can help.

Comment: Try looking in `vendor/sail/runtimes`

Comment: Thanks @yainspan I tried adding a value in the `php.ini` there but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 5):

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#sail-customization

`sail artisan sail:publish`

And then you can customize **php.ini** in **/docker** directory and rebuild your image with new params.

Comment: I had to shut down docker, then run php artisan sail:publish

Comment: it still doesn't seem to be taking the settings in the php.ini, i'm not able to upload a 64M SQL into my phpadmin which I have loading docker-composer.yml

Comment: Did you figure this out? I find it crazy how many extra steps everything takes when using docker.

Comment: using sail:publish makes upgrading a bit more tedious in the future because all of the configuration is copied up to the project folder. Mounting a local php.ini in the docker-compose.yml is a better idea in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because php.ini is only copied during [docker-compose build](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.1/Dockerfile#L54). So you could modify it and build your image again. However I would opt to map the php.ini file [through a volume from the host to the container in docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/stubs/docker-compose.stub#L20).

Comment: I don't see where you have put php.ini in the link? My docker-compose files looks the same

Comment: @warmwhisky I think my link is outdates due to updates to the repo, the copy line is now on [line 58](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.1/Dockerfile#L58)

Comment: I did try mapping from another source, but nothing I done worked. I rebuilt, restarted, tried all ini files in published docker directory and nothing works. Crazy really I spent 2 hours trying to put a zero in a text file and gave up

Comment: The mount for docker-compose would look something like this:
 - './path/to/your/php.ini:/etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/999-sail-overrides.ini'

Keep in mind, the ini files are loaded alphabetically where "999-sail-overrides" is a contrived name and intended to load last.